# How to sanitize a user generated string that is going to be stored in a JSON object?

Tags: python, mysql, json, bottle

I have a comment box which takes user inputs as comments. I need to store these comments in a JSON object. the JSON is stored in the database. How should I go about sanitizing my input so that the JSON doesn't break.

I use bottle's request.params to get the comment text and then I create a dictionary with comment_text as a key, among other keys:

```
dict = {{..., 
         'comment_text' : request.params.get('comment_text'), 
          ....}}
```

and then I do:

```
json_vals = json.dumps(dict)
```

json_vals is then stored in the MySQL DB.

Comment: escape all the things.

Comment: Which database do you want to use? Do you use a framework? Please give more details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `json` module's `dump`/`dumps` functions handle escaping of arbitrary strings for you. Your database may then need you to escape things further, but there's almost certainly an easy way to do that too. Don't try to do the escaping manually with string formatting, use the APIs.

Comment: @Blckknght: So you mean I don't need to do anything else to the comment string before json.dumps?

Comment: @Gaurav: You might *want* to do other validation first (based on what you plan on doing with the data after you pull it back out of your database), but `json.dumps` won't choke on any valid Python string, as far as I can tell. If the JSON format requires escaping for some of the string's contents (such as quotation marks), it will apply the escaping automatically.

Comment: What problem are you trying to avoid (or solve) by "sanitizing?"